# Why q and page are hidden fields in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, hidden-field

ActiveAdmin (v2.4.0) has a private method called `except_hidden_fields`:

```
def except_hidden_fields
 [:q, :page]
end
```

This means that is not possible to access the params and the page from the ActiveAdmin which can be frustrating sometimes. I wanted to know the reason behind that.

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb).

Comment: You should raise this question with the author of the gem or to the community at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin. Since you are new here,this should help https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll do that then. Thank you! @sureshprasanna70